# Limiting number of items in ngrepeat and then adding up all others in to one using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, limit

I am listing out number of users the folder is shared as a Letter avatar in AngularJS and also I know how to limit it to a certain number. But can you help me how to display the remaining entries by adding up? For example, `+1`, `+2`, etc.

I am attaching a sample image and code for displaying the avatar in HTML file.
[image: Sample Img]

Tag from HTML Page!

```
 <td class="project-people" ng-repeat="emp in employee">

   <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="img/a2.jpg" 
        tooltip-placement="top" uib-tooltip="1{{emp.employee_Name}} is the owner">

   <ng-letter-avatar shape="round" avatarcustombgcolor dynamic="true"
        ng-repeat="usr in emp.employee_Shared |limitTo:2" data="{{usr.employee_Name}}">
   </ng-letter-avatar>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `User_Shared.length - yourLimit`

In this case your limit is `2` but you can store it inside a variable that would be easier to maintain

```
<td class="project-people" ng-repeat="cli in client">
    <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="img/a2.jpg" tooltip-placement="top" uib-tooltip="1{{cli.Owner_Name}} is the owner">
    <ng-letter-avatar shape="round" avatarcustombgcolor dynamic="true" ng-repeat="usr in cli.User_Shared |limitTo:2" data="{{usr.User_Name}}">
    </ng-letter-avatar>
    <ng-letter-avatar shape="round" avatarcustombgcolor dynamic="true" data="cli.User_Shared.length - 2"></ng-letter-avatar>
</td>
```

Comment: Works good with some modification.Anyways thanks for the answer!